# How to create a Bootstrap ListGroup with Dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I’d like to create a list-group which includes DropDown menus in Bootstrap.

Important: I‘d like to click on the listgroup row- not only the text should be clickable!

If I do it my way, the list-group-items with the DorpDownMenu have rounded edges on the top.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Without Dropdown</a>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DropdownMenu1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DropdownMenu2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item4</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item5</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Without Dropdown</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```